# Production issue came in iOS 13.3.1 and iOS 13.2.3. How to check this issue in macOS version (Venture version 13.5.2)?

Tags: xcode

Downloaded Old version Xcode i…e (iOS 13.3.1). And try to install this version of Xcode in my Mac, But this Xcode version not supported in the current  macOS version (Venture version 13.5.2). How to test this issue?

Unable to install Xcode 13.3.1 in Mac os version (Venture version 13.5.2). How to install Xcode version 13.3.1 in macOS Venture 13.5.2.

Comment: You don't need the old Xcode. You need to create an older simulator or test on a device with that version of iOS. Really though, drop support for < iOS 14 or even < iOS 15

Comment: Thanks for the quick support @Paulw11. My current Xcode version is 14.3.1 and platform list i am not able to see iOS 13 iphone simulators is there way to add this simulator.

Comment: You will need to extract it from the older Xcode you can download from the Apple Developer site -https://medium.com/@staceypyee/say-hi-ventura-bye-old-ios-simulators-4a0615bef097

Comment: Downloaded older Xcode(13.3.1) from Developer account. But unable to install older Xcode version in My mac.My Mac current version macOS Venture(13.5.2).Old Xcode version not supported for my Mac. Unable to open Old Xcode in Mac.

Comment: You will probably need to install an old version of macOS in order to run the old version of Xcode.  Does the issue affect iOS 13.7?  You are talking about a 4 year old operating system.  Any device that can run iOS 13 can run iOS 15.  There is no real reason to support iOS 13.

Comment: This issue effected in iOS 13.3.1

Comment: There is zero reason to support iOS 13.3.1. Users can (and should) upgrade to the latest version that their device supports.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Paulw11.